# Display individal substrings of Split() or string of Join() function in individual cells (VBA Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, string

I'm new to VBA and cannot figure this question out for the life of me. I apologize if I'm not using the proper words to describe my problem:

I have a function in VBA that opens a URL which downloads a csv file. I have the variable assigned to that download declared "As String". Then, I split it into rows and split the relevant row (I need information in the second row) into columns.  I can now use the function to display any of the information in any of the seven columns of the second row, but only one at a time. I can also use the Join() method to display the entire second row in one cell with the substrings separate by a comma.

Goal: I want to be able to customize which pieces of information (substrings) from the second row to display, and I want them displayed in their own adjacent cells (adjacent by columns). This can be accomplished by using the "Text to Columns" feature on the Data ribbon, but I want it converted in the visual basic code itself. Thank you!!

Here is my Code:

```
Function DailyRange(YahooTicker As String, Optional dtDate As Variant)
' Date is optional - if omitted, use today. If value is not a date, throw error.
If IsMissing(dtDate) Then
dtDate = Date
Else
If Not (IsDate(dtDate)) Then
DailyRange = CVErr(xlErrNum)
End If
End If

Dim dtPrevDate As Date
Dim strURL As String, strCSV As String, strRows() As String, strColumns() As String
Dim DailyRows As Variant
Dim dbDate As String
Dim dbHigh As Double, dbLow As Double, dbClose As Double, dbVolume As Double

dtPrevDate = dtDate - 7

' Compile the request URL with start date and end date
strURL = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" & YahooTicker & _
"&a=" & Month(dtPrevDate) - 1 & _
"&b=" & Day(dtPrevDate) & _
"&c=" & Year(dtPrevDate) & _
"&d=" & Month(dtDate) - 1 & _
"&e=" & Day(dtDate) & _
"&f=" & Year(dtDate) & _
"&g=d&ignore=.csv"

' Debug.Print strURL

Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", strURL, False
http.Send
strCSV = http.responseText

' Debug.Print strCSV

' THIS IS WHERE I RUN INTO THE PROBLEM    
' I want the most recent information which is in row 2, just below the table headings.
' I want date, price open, high, low, close, and volume which positions are shown below
strRows() = Split(strCSV, Chr(10)) ' split the CSV into rows
strColumns = Split(strRows(1), ",") ' split the relevant row into columns. 1 means 2nd row, starting at index 0
DailyRows = Join(strColumns, ",")
dbDate = strColumns(0) ' means 1st position, date
dbHigh = strColumns(2) ' means 3rd position, price high
dbLow = strColumns(3) ' means 4th position, price low
dbClose = strColumns(4) ' 4 means: 5th position, starting at index 0
dbVolume = strColumns(5) ' means 6th position, volume

' Now, how do I display the information I want in their own cells?
'DailyRange = dbDate & dbHigh & dbLow & dbClose & dbVolume
'DailyRange = strColumns
'DailyRange = strCSV

 DailyRange = DailyRows


Set http = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to open a CSV, why not use the Workbooks.Open() method to open the file, and then manipulate the data that way?